# the purpose of the field before signature in P2WPKH

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, p2wpkh, serialization

what is the purpose of that `02` in this P2WPKH transaction :

```
01000000
0001
01
d6f3994ab779ac849996a6235699ced672fa4b8334f825a2f1fcb4081c5b0c62
00000000
00
ffffffff
02
1027000000000000
16
00140429fc6e543ff7b4b75d0c6a60013c125827aa66
5716040000000000
16
00145951ac8720b1865ba633d19eaa6473afae7c46b3


02  -----> WHAT IS THE PURPOSE OF THIS?


483045022100b826e4123a66ab38f2e5f4ede2c50c1ce93bbfbdbdc2997a6e1ff09fe964349d022060a14f272ba521ec71f022922a855bda8827b7262ca181df755fdf42f656cc97012102e2ae4b9e9d86f03d511c4716ce3af351428201f2ff0378d00c7e097fbbbcb95
000000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the number of witness items in the witness stack of input #0 of the transaction.

See [BIP144](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0144.mediawiki#serialization) for the serialization format used by segwit transactions:

> the only witness objects type supported are script witnesses which consist of a stack of byte arrays. It is encoded as a var_int item count followed by each item encoded as a var_int length followed by a string of bytes. Each txin has its own script witness. The number of script witnesses is not explicitly encoded as it is implied by txin_count. Empty script witnesses are encoded as a zero byte. The order of the script witnesses follows the same order as the associated txins.

Comment: thanks for anwsering, this is the transaction : https://mempool.space/tx/ef7d947fe4436a966ee27a430ec6474ac2004323a78686fd9bdc4dec2e53fe14#flow=&vout=1

where is the witness item? i'm new to bitcoin btw. is the signature and public key which two items?

Comment: The first witness item of this input has length 0x48 (and comprises the 0x48 following bytes `30450221...cc9701`). The second witness item has length 0x21 (and comprises the 0x21 following bytes `02e2ae4b...fbbbcb95`). It's a P2WPKH spend, so exactly two witness items are expected: an ECDSA signature and a public key, in that order.

Comment: Got It, Thank You.